# OpenCV on MacOS with Netbeans

Tags: java, macos, opencv

I install the 4.1.0 version of OpenCV on MacOS (Version 10.12.6) with the following command :

```
brew install --build-from-source opencv
```

After that I get my .jar file and I added it to my netbeans project. 
And I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java410 in java.library.path
```

when I try this code :

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
System.out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());
```

I already search what I can add to the VM options but I don't found it.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The error you recieve, says something like it could not find the opencv.jar file on your current location. You must eighter move the jar file and the dynalink file to the a folder included in java.library.path. Or add the folder to the java.library.path.

this link has an explanaiton of how to do it.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/